# What was the name of this Cleric Prestige Class that shapes metal with its bare hands?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, prestige-class, product-identification, dnd-3e

I know this is a vague question, but I seem to remember a Cleric prestige class that was very into crafting metalic items. They even became able to shape metals with their bare hands without the use of forges or tools at later levels... I can't find it anymore, can anyone point me in the right direction?

It was a class feature. They became able to use their hands as war hammers at something like level 8, and they could also shape virtually any metal as long as they could put their hands on on both sides. Not a metal door from 1 side, but if they could somehow touch both sides, they could shape it to virtually anything they wanted. They were proficient with any weapons or armor they crafted, but they didn't really get any special features for using weapons or armor otherwise...

As far as I can remember, it wasn't a 3rd party prestige class, but having not been able to find it anywhere it might be...

Comment: The only reason I recognized what you were describing was due to using Scarred Lands material for many years.

Comment: Thank you again for knowing where thic sould be found. I've used this class before, but it's been years and several campaigns ago, and then I printed up what Ineeded... For the characters I like to play it's a great class! Thanks again!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Hammer of Urgan

> **Hammerhand (Su):** At 5th level and beyond, Urgan’s divine blessings allow his follower to beat and shape metal with his bare hands. The hammer of Urgan always counts as having all the necessary tools to use his Craft skills, even if he lacks a workshop, hammer, tongs, and other items. In addition, his unarmed strikes have the same damage, critical threat, and critical multiplier as a warhammer with a size equal to his own. He does not gain the benefits of Improved Unarmed Strike unless he has that feat.

**Source:** Book of Hallowed Might II: Portents and Visions

- Publisher: Malhavoc Press
- Authors: Monte Cook and Mike Mearls
- Chapter Four: The World Forge
- Page: 47

Answer (score 3):

You may be thinking of the spell "Shape Metal" Cleric 4, Sor/Wis 5 from Races of Faerun that acts as stone shape, but for metal. You *probably aren't* thinking of the Shaper of Form from Dragon Compendium, but their Like Begets Like ability matches your requirements. You might also be thinking of a PrC which grants you the greed, dwarf, or trade domains (which grant access to Fabricate)

Answer (score 0):

Whereas the Hammer of Urgan is probably what you're looking for, I'd like to point out that I found what is basically an upgrade of that prestige class called the Forge Hand in the *Quintessential Dwarf II* book. It just all around does what the Hammer of Urgan does, better.

Comment: What makes it an upgrade/better? Does it actually check all the same boxes?

Comment: For the most part, yes. There's also more levels that take the benefits of the class higher.

Comment: Adding that analysis to your answer would be a big improvement. It may not be what OP was trying to find, but others might be interested if you can support your assertions in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I've recently had to reorder The Quintessential Dwarf II, so I don't currently have access to said book but I will when my new copy gets here. I should be able to support said assertions then.

Comment: You may want to hold off on the answer, then. At the moment it reads more as unsupported conjecture.

Comment: Granted. I guess I merely got excited since I rarely see anyone besides myself interested in such a class. Apologies.

Comment: Maybe someone who has it can help with a quote:)